# Rotate and Scale Around Different Origins using Local Coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, affine-geometry, geometric-transformation

How can I chain rotate and scale operations (each with different origins) while keeping each operation origin in relation to the original local component space?

Using matrix denotation (i.e. *T* for translation matrix, *R* for the rotation matrix, and *S* for the scaling matrix) I'm performing the following operations on my object:

\begin{gather*}
T*R*S
\end{gather*}

$T$ takes us from a global to local coordinate frame, then $R$ and $S$ rotate and subsequently scale our object. Since we are rotating and scaling around unique points in the object, the operation breaks down to:

1. `mat` = $I$
2. `mat` = `mat` $*$ $T$
3. `mat` = `mat` $*$ translation matrix to $R$ origin $*$ $R$ $*$ translation matrix to $-R$ origin
4. `mat` = `mat` $*$ translation matrix to $S$ origin $*$ $S$ $*$ translation matrix to $-S$ origin

However, this produces an object that is both scaled *and* rotated with respect to the original object. For example, if we scale by $2$x  about the bottom-left corner $(0,0)$ and rotate $45^{\circ}$ about the center $(1.5, 1.5)$ we produce the following:

[image]

What operation(s) need to be edited in order to achieve rotating about the newly scaled object's center:

[image]

Comment: Can you add the matrix operations for the 1st image? Apparently the red square has longer sides than the green square.